# Is it possible to make a class that has two superclasses in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, superclass

I currently have a class that already has a superclass. I realized I also want to call methods from a different existing class, but don't have it defined as a superclass. Is it possible to assign a second superclass to my existing child class or is that not possible.

If it is possible, how would I go about doing it. If it isn't possible, what's a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. Objective-C is single-inheritance.

Depending on your situation, **Composition** might be the right pattern to get around this: let's say you have class Foo, and you also want instances of Foo to inherit behavior from class Bar.

You can keep an instance of Bar as an instance variable inside Foo and delegate method calls to it. Because Objective-C is dynamically typed, you can simply cast your instance of Foo as an instance of Bar and pass it to any code expecting a Bar. As long as Foo responds to all the same methods that Bar does, no one will know the difference.

If you want to get fancy (or if Bar has too many methods and you don't want to write out each one), you can use message forwarding to pass along any messages your Foo class doesn't recognize to the Bar instance. Look up the documentation on `forwardInvocation:` to see how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Objective C doesn't support the multiple inheritance but you can achieve this functionality by using the interfaces.